# How to catch any link click event

Tags: angularjs

I want to process a click event when a link url is actual (url to current page). The problem is that links are not editable by me (these are users content), so I can't add any directives to the links. In that case I want to catch and process any link click event to solve my problem. But AngularJS doesn't trigger any event when a link url is actual. If url wouldn't be actual, I could use the $locationChangeStart or $locationChangeSuccess events of $location service. But in my case I can't use these events because they are never triggered. Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use either jQuery or raw JS to listen for click events on `<a>` tags within the user-generated content, then use `$rootScope.$broadcast` to notify the rest of the app. If you want to change the URL, just take it from the `<a>` tag using JS and pass it as an argument to `$broadcast`. Then call `$location.url()` to change route manually.

Comment: If you have provided some sample it will be great !